# To run the java file that use a external jar file

Tags: java

I want to run the java class file that uses a external jar file ,
    How to  compile it. below is my command ,that i have tried it.

```
    javac set classpath="d:\vinod\text.jar" Generate.java
```

Comment: Try: `javac -cp d:\vinod\text.jar Generate.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use eclipse IDE to add the external jar file easily. just select the
    project and press alt+enter then java build path , add the external
    jar file and refresh the eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

say `javac -cp d:\vinod\text.jar" Generate.java`  or set the environment variable CLASSPATH to point to the `text.jar` file and  say `javac Generate.jar`

to run the file you need to use the same arguments with the `java` program instead of `javac`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set path = %path%;"d:\vinod\text.jar"
javac Generate.java // Or use -cp <path> command line argument
java Generate // if main method is present in Generate class.
```